# mediaRouteTheme not found

Tags: java, android, chromecast, google-cast

When I try to create a style as indicated by:
https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/android_sender_advanced#customize_cast_button like **this:**

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">#7788FF</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#7700FF</item>
    <item name="mediaRouteTheme">@style/CustomMediaRouterTheme</item>
</style>

<style name="CustomMediaRouterTheme" parent="Theme.MediaRouter">
    <item name="mediaRouteButtonStyle">@style/CustomMediaRouteButtonStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="CustomMediaRouteButtonStyle" parent="Widget.MediaRouter.Light.MediaRouteButton">
    <item name="buttonTint">#CCCC00</item>
</style>
```

**I get the following error:**

```
Error:error: style attribute 'attr/mediaRouteTheme (aka com.*:attr/mediaRouteTheme)' not found.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you including the right media router lib: android.support.v7.mediarouter

Comment: Same problem here, but I don't get the error, the color doesn't work. Did you find a solution ?

Answer (score 3):

I Used this dependency in **build.gradle**   `compile 'com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:25.3.1'`

and in `style.xml`

```
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="mediaRouteTheme">@style/CustomMediaRouterTheme</item>
</style>


<style name="CustomMediaRouterTheme" parent="Theme.MediaRouter">
    <item name="mediaRouteButtonStyle">@style/CustomMediaRouteButtonStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="CustomMediaRouteButtonStyle" parent="Widget.MediaRouter.Light.MediaRouteButton">
    <item name="buttonTint">#CCCC00</item>
</style>
```

its working fine, not getting any error. try with this gradle dependency.

Comment: You're right, it's working with 25.3.1. But it's not working since 26... Any idea to workaround this  with version 27.0.2 ?

Answer (score 2):

From support library v26.0.0, the "buttonTint" is changed to "mediaRouteButtonTint".

Replacing "mediaRouteButtonTint" with "buttonTint" would fix the issue.

Comment: Thanks, you're the google guy who answers me or just an opportunist ? ;-) https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/73592542

Comment: Works with `androidx` as well.

Answer (score 1):

Found the following solution from: https://smartapps.egeniq.com/style-mediaroutebutton-change-chromecast-icon-color-ecc98d72abe4

```
 Context castContext = new ContextThemeWrapper(this.getBaseContext(), android.support.v7.mediarouter.R.style.Theme_MediaRouter);
    Drawable drawable = null;
    TypedArray a = castContext.obtainStyledAttributes(null,
            android.support.v7.mediarouter.R.styleable.MediaRouteButton, android.support.v7.mediarouter.R.attr.mediaRouteButtonStyle, 0);
    drawable = a.getDrawable(
            android.support.v7.mediarouter.R.styleable.MediaRouteButton_externalRouteEnabledDrawable);
    a.recycle();
    MediaRouteButton mrb = (MediaRouteButton)findViewById(R.id.media_route_menu_item);
    DrawableCompat.setTint(drawable, 0xFFCCCCCC);
    mrb.setRemoteIndicatorDrawable(drawable);
    CastButtonFactory.setUpMediaRouteButton(this, mrb);
```

Comment: I don't use a MediaRouteButton but a MediaRouteMenuItem. I try the same code by replacing the mrb line definition with mine, but the color doesn't apply

Comment: Thanks, that seems to be the only solution that works with nowaday's latest libraries.